# How to test AVAudioEnigne and AVFoundation?

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I am developing a small wrapper to create a framework on AVFoundation that wraps up some functionality and I want to create tests around it.

I'm calling this only on the initializer of my class implementation as it only needs to be run once. I don't want to add logic specific that avoids this line to be run when I'm running the tests but I am having trouble testing functionality on this class like reading an audio file and appending it to the audio buffer.

```swift
private let mixerNode = AVAudioMixerNode()

// Used to get audio from the microphone.
private lazy var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

private func configureAudioEngine() {
    // Get the native audio format of the engine's input bus.
    let inputFormat = audioEngine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)

    // Set an output format
    // let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 48000, channels: 1)
    let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(
        standardFormatWithSampleRate: audioEngine.inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0).sampleRate,
        channels: 1)

    // Mixer node converts the input
    audioEngine.attach(mixerNode)

    // Attach the mixer to the microphone input and the output of the audio engine.
    // Crash on the line below, (shown on the lines below with the prints)
    audioEngine.connect(audioEngine.inputNode, to: mixerNode, format: inputFormat)
    audioEngine.connect(mixerNode, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: outputFormat)

    // Install a tap on the mixer node to capture the microphone audio.
    mixerNode.installTap(onBus: 0,
                         bufferSize: 8192,
                         format: outputFormat) { [weak self] buffer, audioTime in
        // Add captured audio to the buffer
        // TODO: Do operation on the buffer data that's being received...
    }
}
```

I am seeing inconsistencies between running this on the device and running the tests as the returned `AVAudioFormat` is different. These two prints below are from the same line indicated above

**`AVAudioEngine` during a test**

```swift
Tests iOS-Runner[4515:894511] [aurioc] AURemoteIO.cpp:1123  failed: 561015905 (enable 1, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, deinterleaved> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, deinterleaved>)
```

**`AVAudioEngine` when running on device**

```swift
<AVAudioFormat 0x2834962b0:  1 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32>
```